# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "cursi"?

Tags: etimología, historia

El adjetivo "cursi" tiene el significado de pretender ser elegante, refinado, bonito o muy afectivo sin llegar realmente a serlo, y pasando a ser por el contrario un poco ridículo y hasta vergonzoso.

En [la entrada del DRAE para "cursi"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BkfJV86) se indica que es de "etimología discutida".

¿Cuál es la etimología (o las diferentes teorías sobre ella) de "cursi"?

Answer (score 3):

Te indico la etimología que da Corominas en su diccionario etimológico abreviado:

> **CURSI** 'de mal gusto', 1865. Vocablo semijergal, de origen incierto. Como aparece primeramente en Andalucía, debió de tomarse modernamente del árabe marroquí, donde *kúrsi* significa 'figurón, personaje importante', y es aplicación metafórica de la palabra corriente para 'silla', que en otras partes se registra en el sentido de 'ciencia, saber', 'sabio, docto' y 'cátedra de profesor o predicador'; de ahí se pasaría a 'pedante', 'presuntuoso', y a la acepción española.

En el CORDE encuentro este caso como el más antiguo, que resulta ser incluso anterior a la fecha citada por Corominas:

> *En el baile que el otro día dió, ocurrió un incidente que retrata al vivo su carácter y modo de ser, presumido y cursi al mismo tiempo.*
>
> Juan Valera, "Correspondencia", 1847-1857 (España).

De hecho en diccionarios aparece desde 1853, y en el de la RAE desde 1869, aunque en ningún momento se atreven a proponer siquiera una posible etimología.

Sobre la posible etimología proveniente del apellido Sicour, es interesante leer este artículo del ABC del 21 de octubre de 1962, titulado [*La cursilería y las niñas de Sicour*](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/1962/10/21/047.html), de Ramón Solís.

> ¡Cómo serían de cursis las niñas de Sicour, que hubo que inventar para ellas una palabra! La palabra cursi es muy reciente y, aunque no lo reconoce así algún diccionario etimológico, su historia parte del Cádiz de 1835 a 1840 y sus protagonistas fueron las niñas de Sicour, hijas de un sastre francés [...]. Cualquier gaditano que esté vinculado a la ciudad por más de tres generaciones ha oído contar la historia. Es incomprensible el recelo con que muchos investigadores y eruditos acogen la tradición popular y más aún cuando [...] la tradición se remonta a poco más de un siglo y nuestros abuelos pudieron darnos pelos y señales de las andanzas de las citadas señoritas, de sus paseos por la plaza de Mina y sus trajes llamativos.
>
> [...]
>
> Las niñas de Sicour eran hijas de un sastre francés que llegó un día a Cádiz con los últimos modelos de París. Las niñas, además de mal gusto, debían de tener una fuerte personalidad, a su manera y, sobre todo, debían de ser decididas y de las que no se paraban en barras. Lo cierto es que, sin tener medios económicos para ello, ni elegancia, ni esa posición social que la época imponía para poder figurar en sociedad, se lanzaron un día a la plaza de Mina de Cádiz dispuestas a disputar en elegancia con las más plantadas. Eran los años 1835 a 1840. Cádiz era ambiente propicio para la cursilería.
>
> [...]
>
> Las niñas fueron unas incomprendidas. Los estudiantes de Medicina, que ya no tenían uniforme de oficiales de Marina [...] ni aquella seriedad dieciochesca de sus primeros años [...], la toman con ellas. Una copla aguda, graciosa, oportuna, las hace populares. El estribillo de la canción era sencillo y repetido muy rápidamente da lugar a la palabra "cursi". Decía:
>
> ```
>     Las niñas de "Sicour"
>     Sicur, Sicur, Sicur
>     Sicur, Sicur, Sicur.
> ```

El artículo termina con un par de referencias. La primera es al apéndice "Diccionario de voces gaditanas" incluido en la obra "Nombres de calles y plazas de Cádiz", de 1857, en el que define la palabra "cursi" que por entonces era aún patrimonio de la ciudad. Y cita también una aparición de la palabra en la revista gaditana "La estrella", en [un artículo](https://webs.ucm.es/info/especulo/numero25/cursi.html) del 25 de diciembre de 1842 titulado "Lo cursi", que es básicamente una amplia definición de la palabra (se enlaza un texto sobre el artículo, el cual se incluye completo al final, aunque se puede ver una reproducción del principio del mismo en el artículo citado del ABC, [página 49](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/1962/10/21/049.html)). La prensa gaditana comienza a usar el término desde entonces. Incluso cita que desde 1870 se usa en la ciudad el propio apellido "sicur" como sinónimo de "cursi", debido probablemente a que ya no se esperaban represalias de la familia Sicour.

Si la palabra se usaba en textos escritos desde 1842, las fechas encajas con las primeras apariciones de la misma en diccionarios, en 1853 y 1869 como se ha citado al principio de esta respuesta.

Por último, la gráfica de NGram que no deja lugar a dudas acerca de cuándo se produjo la explosión del uso de la palabra:

[image: Cursi]

Resumiendo: que existe una etimología popular que dice que viene de Cádiz del apellido Sicour por repetición y alteración de las sílabas, la cual Corominas no se cree porque dice que no hay evidencias de que existieran las tales hermanas Sicour, e intenta tirar por otra etimología, que puede ser incluso menos creíble que la popular (aunque mantiene el origen andaluz) y la RAE dice por tanto que la etimología es discutida.